# How to update a parameter in a job in Oracle SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have just created a job using SQL Developer build-in wizard and i would like to change the parameters of the created job from my application.
The job is launching a stored procedure every day at 7 o'clock.

In the application I have two fields:

1. Disable: true/false
2. Hour: 10:00

And this is my job and fields I would like to update depending on what was selected in the app:

[image]

I see two ways of doing it:

1. Make the fields dependent on the values in the table
2. Make a pl/sql block that updates the values

Of course I don't know how to do it (in the first option the select statement doesn't work and in the second I don't know how to acces the jobs fields)

Please help

Comment: You need to drop and re-create the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Begin 
dbms_scheduler.disable( 'ATOS."job_email_notifications"' );

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE ( name => 'ATOS."job_email_notifications"', attribute => 'repeat_interval', value => 'freq=daily;byday=FRI,SAT;byhour=20;byminute=0; bysecond=0');--change value--as per need

dbms_scheduler.enable( 'ATOS."job_email_notifications"' );
End;
/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, however this doesn't work for me, the error says: Error report -
ORA-27476: "ATOS.JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS" does not exist

ORA-06512: at line 2
*Cause:    A database object was specified that does not exist.

Comment: post the output of below query :
select * from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name ='JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS';

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Maybe I have a different scheduler name or sth?

Comment: try this 
select * from all_scheduler_jobs where job_name ='JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS';

It seems you have rights to view dba views.

Comment: select * from all_scheduler_jobs where job_name ='job_email_notifications'; with smaller letters it worked. I can see my job

Comment: use the code provided by me again.I have updated my answer.
Begin 
dbms_scheduler.disable( 'job_email_notifications' );

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE ( name => 'job_email_notifications', attribute => 'repeat_interval', value => 'freq=daily;byday=FRI,SAT;byhour=20;byminute=0; bysecond=0');--change value--as per need

dbms_scheduler.enable( 'job_email_notifications' );
End;

Comment: I tried changing job names before and it didn't work. It still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121695/discussion-between-prashant-mishra-and-aleksander-lipka).

Answer (score 0):

Use below procedure for dynamic updates based on values

```
Create or replace procedure change_attributes(a_job_name varchar2, a_param varchar2, a_new_val varchar2)
As
Begin 
dbms_scheduler.disable( a_job_name);

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE ( name => a_job_name,attribute => a_param, value => a_new_val);

dbms_scheduler.enable( a_job_name);
End;
/
```